# PHP: How to seek backwards to find last N lines

Tags: php, tail

I suppose I could call tail, but that would mean depending on an external program. Is there a way to do this in an efficient way using only PHP?

---

**Update:** For those interested, I followed the advice I got in the accepted answer and tried to implement on myself. Put it [on my blog](http://www.geekality.net/?p=1654) =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to reproduce `tail`, basically. Open the file, jump to the end, then start reading backwards. Read a chunk, count line breaks, repeat until linebreak count > number of lines desired, then dump out everything from that one linebreak onwards.

Answer (score 8):

So you want the last `n` lines of a string?

```
function getLastLines($string, $n = 1) {
    $lines = explode("\n", $string);

    $lines = array_slice($lines, -$n);

    return implode("\n", $lines);
}
```

You can then call this with `getLastLines($str, $num);`, where `$num` is a positive integer and `$str` is a string you want to chop up.

If you want something different, e.g. using a file as the source, you'll need something different -- perhaps using `file` instead of `explode`.

Comment: This would pull the whole thing into memory though, wouldn't it?

Comment: Right...I think the goal would be to call `fopen()` using mode `a+` and seek backwards...not read in the entire file first.

Comment: +1 i already had the whole string in memory for another purpose - this is exactly what i was looking for to prevent the need to reopen the file a second time

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use file. It loads the whole file in an array, one line per item. Use count to count the total linecount, subtract 100 en from that index you can do what you want with the lines.

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

For very large files, this is not really efficient. Then you better use fstat to get the filesize, fseek to go back an x number of bytes, count the number of lines you can read en possibly seek further back until you have found 100 lines. I bet tools like tail don't count from the beginning but do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read in the file as an array, you can then use [array_splice](https://www.php.net/array_splice) to specify the last N lines:

**test.txt**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**test.php**

```
$lines = file('test.txt');
$line_number = 5;

echo implode("", array_splice($lines, count($lines) - $line_number));
```

**output**

```
$ php test.php
6
7
8
9
10
```